# Optimisation of zxing.net QR decode

Tags: zxing

I am having great success with zxing on .NET and trying to get the best speed for decoding QR Barcodes (I have a lot to do -- 1.8M). The code I am using (well bits of it):

```
// Create Barcode decoder
BarcodeReader q = new BarcodeReader();
q.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
q.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
q.AutoRotate = true; // Not necessary for QR?
q.TryHarder = false;

// Decode result
Result[] r = q.DecodeMultiple(imageFile);
```

My code is a little smarter in that it is in a loop and tries harder if it doesn't find it the first time.

Is there a way to add a zone, ROI or smaller area to speed up the detection?

Any other recommendations to improve performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest way with ZXing.Net for QR codes is the following:

```
// Create Barcode decoder
BarcodeReader q = new BarcodeReader();
q.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
q.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
q.AutoRotate = false;
q.TryHarder = false;

// Decode result
Result r = q.Decode(imageFile);
```

But it decodes only the first QR code which is found.
Avoid DecodeMultiple if you don't need it.
All other options should only be used if really necessary.
AutoRotate isn't necessary for QR code decoding.

If your images are really big shrink them before decoding.
For most cases there is no need for images with a bigger resolution than 1000 pixels.
The only exceptions are really tiny QR codes.

Another good optimization is the use of an image source which gives grayscale images.
A lot of CPU cycles are needed for the calculation of the luminance values from
RGB images. The fastest option are 8 bit grayscale images.

Comment: Ok.  I am doing bitonal images, so there's no RGB.  Is there a way to get zxing.net to limit the region it looks in, rather than the expensive option of creating a new bitmap of the region?

Comment: Yes, you can use the crop method which resides on the ...LuminanceSource classes. That way works best with the current source from repositories trunk because there is a Decode method which directly uses a ...LuminanceSource instance. With the current release 0.11 of ZXing.Net you have to use the BarcodeReader with an own CreateLuminanceSource delegate.

Comment: Why do you suggest avoiding DecodeMultiple. I'm working on a project where I need to scan multiple QR codes in one image.

Comment: I wrote "avoid it if you don't need it". If you need it in your use case then use it. It's ok. But everything has a performance impact.

Comment: This technique seems to be deprecated.